# 2012 Golf TDI - manual trans. mount repair

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, motor-mounts

So, I brought my car in to shop class for a vibration and noise issue, and it turned out that the transmission mount bolts had almost all come out (one was hanging on thankfully), and on inspection the holes that the bolts thread into on the transmission had been stripped out. My instructor said he could repair the holes if I brought in some bigger bolts, wanting me to get some M14 x 1.5 x 65mm and blue thread locker, but sadly I can't find the bolts in any in any store. I read on other forums that the bolts for the trans mount are TTY, but I may question is could helicoil on the bolts that I already have, or should I get new bolts and helicoil those?

Answer (score 4):

You can absolutely use a Helicoil as a repair. My opinion is, it is actually a better repair. I understand why your shop teacher would suggest drilling/tapping it out to the next size, as that would be the cheaper option. A Helicoil kit in any size isn't what I'd call "cheap", though probably cheaper than not fixing it at all. Both solutions will work, but if you cannot find the bolt of the right size, and can find a Helicoil, I'd definitely go that route.